# Solidity memory pointer

Tags: solidity, memory

Is there any way I can use a local parameter within multiple functions?
The idea is to save gas when calling functions. A parameter wouldn't have to be copied and be returned every time.

Here's some pseudo code:

```
function A(uint[] array) public pure returns (uint[]) {
    B(*array);  // send a memory pointer?
    return array;    
}

// B directly manipulates the array via the pointer => see no return value
function B(uint[] *array) internal pure {
    // something
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if I understood you correctly, but as far as I have understood arrays are not copied between function calls, as they can contain millions of elements. They are passed by a reference. Somebody correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You're right. I was interpreting the Remix debugger wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved as Mikko explained in the comment.